# Selecting element from typescript union by its value

Tags: typescript

I have union of such shape:

```js
type Message = 
  | { type: 'first', someParam: any } // let it be AMsg
  | { type: 'second', someAnotherParam: any, andOneAnother: any }
```

I want to get an element of this union as a separate type like so:

```js
type AMsg = MessageOfType<'first'> // = { type: 'first', someParam: any }
```

I've tried to write my own MessageOfType:

```js
type MessageOfType<T extends Message['type']> = Message['type'] extends T ? Message : never
```

but it allways returns `never`.

What should I use to get an element or some elements with `type` matching needed value from union?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use the predefined conditional type `Extract` for this:

```
type Message = 
  | { type: 'first', someParam: any } // let it be AMsg
  | { type: 'second', someAnotherParam: any, andOneAnother: any }

type AMsg = Extract<Message, { type: 'first' }>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzaBeKBYAUFKAPlAN5SiQBcUA5AGYCWATvMNQDRTwD2AthAApJGSHlSQA7EFAC+UAPRyoAGwjAo9NQCNoAQRjwUufEVLkIVavAgBjLuIAm7Trwg7xXYAAsIjQcNFQEiAcEvYA8uKu7l4+YpIyuLhmUHoGUJgAogAewMLWwAA8cIioEBym4OY0DMysMgB8UEA)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing type acrobatics you might just want to refactor:

```
 type Message = AMsg | BMsg
 type AMsg = { type: 'first', someParam: any }
 type BMsg = { type: 'second', someAnotherParam: any, andOneAnother: any }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzaBeKBBG8VQB8oAhXFAWAChRJsypMBvKGiALigHIAzASwCd4wTgBoo8APYBbCAAUk-JFI5IAdiCgBfKqxL0mLcOy7wIAYwmqAJqPHSIWVROAALCP3mLlUNSDFqrAHlVBydXdxV1LSoqC1UhHw44RFQMKGZWDh4BIVtJGU8lDgAGaMo4hIAjJIRkNAZ0w0gs0zibMXzQ5zcPBSKoYv9rYK7w-hKy2MsEpDIOHDwGpABuKfjgKEq5vUXMStXKKCOgA)

Comment: In my case there's no need to extract all members just for one I need in my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
type MessageOfType<
T extends Message['type'], 
_M extends Message = Message> = _M extends {type: T} ? _M : never   

type First = MessageOfType<'first'>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzaBeKBYAUFKAPlAN5SiQBcUA5AGYCWATvMNQDRTwD2AthAApJGSHlSQA7EFAC+UAPRyoAGwjAo9NQCNoAQRjwUufEVLkIVavAgBjLuIAm7Trwg7xXYAAsIjQcNFQEiAcEvYA8uKu7l4+YpIyuLhmUHoGUJgAogAewMLWwAA8cIioEBym4OY0DMysMgB8UEA)

Explanation:

- `_M extends Message = Message` local type variable - its generic in order to force TS to narrow the type. Using Message directly would not narrow it
- `_M extends {type: T} ? _M : never` - we say if our `_M` has wanted `type` property then we want it, if not we take never. As `_M` is [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) then the result will be `{ type: 'first', someParam: any } | never`. `never` is neutral for `|` and will be skipped in result we get what we need.

Comment: It's a grate solution! Thanks for that, but I think `Extract` is more standartized and less magical.

Comment: In general this is exactly Extract but explicit

Answer (score 0):

My final solution is this:

```js
type MessageOfType<T extends Message['type']> = Extract<Message, { type: T }>
```

It's less magical then `extends { type: T }` and uses standard type.